# Signs of weak ties to your country of citizenship?

Tags: visa, student-visa, usa

If you've been away from your home country for over 15 years, is that seen as weak ties to your home country when applying for an American student visa?

I am a Taiwanese citizen and I'm now living in Taiwan. The thing is that I went to U.S. with my family and overstayed as a minor. I left when I was 18 (20 days after I turned 18) and then I went to Canada to study as an int'l student. I then worked for 2.5 years. Altogether I spent 6 years in Canada. I returned to Taiwan after 17 years. I just came back 1 year and a half ago.

I'm now applying for a F1 visa.

Comment: How long after your 18th birthday did you leave the US?

Comment: I left 20 days after I turned 18.

Comment: Please edit all the relevant background information into your question. It’s important to include it there rather than in Comments because people who answer may not always notice them, and Comments may be deleted over time.

Comment: Which study visa do you wish to apply for? https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study.html

Comment: How long were you in Canada for? And how long has it been since you've returned to Taiwan?

Comment: @RoboKaren  6 years in Canada. 1 year and a half in Taiwan.

Comment: @Traveller F1 visa (student)